# Can apps read all files in sd card (external removeable micro sd card) without the storage permission?

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd, permissions, android-12

As far as i know. The way Android storage works is as follows. There is internal storage and external storage.

Internal storage is for the apps data only and apps can only access their particular data. No permission needed.

External storage is phone's own storage and also removeable storage (removeable micro sd card) both are to store files and media. Apps need Permission to access through storage permission (read/write).

Does storage permission only means phone's own storage or also the removeable micro sd card? I am confused

I just want to make sure that all files in my micro sd card are safe and apps can't access them without my permission.

Edit: Android 12 but I am also wondering about previous versions. Also I have my sd card mounted as Portable Storage (not Adaptable Storage)

Thank you.
Please let me know

Comment: It depends on your Android version // see [scoped storage](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage) // [edit] your question to add Android version (add in tags as well)

Comment: I have seen the Scoped Storage Page but i am not clear about the answer. Doesn't tell much about removeable micro sd card. And my Android version is 12 and sd card mounted as portable storage.

Comment: See on this site https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Scoped+storage%22

Comment: From the scoped storage link "App-specific directory on external storage
Starting in Android 11, apps cannot create their own app-specific directory on external storage."

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you. But can the apps access the content (files, photos, media) of portable micro sd card without the storage permission?

Comment: (from first link) apps can bypass scoped storage with legacy storage api (API level 29). user can grant access in developer options